# How do I format a dataset for training in Python?

Tags: python, dataset, keras

How do I format a dataset for training in Python?

I have 3000 grayscale BMP images of some handwritten digits (just like MNIST). Now I want to train my model with this dataset (I am using the Keras library) and I am using a convolution neural network for training.

I am using this code to convert one of the images into array

```
`import numpy
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
img = Image.open(open('CMATERdb 3.3.1\Ad02599.bmp')).convert("L")
print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)
img = numpy.asarray(img) / 255.
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)`
```

**and the result from the code was**

None (32, 32) L

[image from the 3000 image want to convert into dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWhjM.png)

Any help how I can convert all images and put them in the same MNIST datast format that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Ali, welcome to SO. This is too unspecific and broad. Please take a look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any library that loads image files into arrays, such as [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/).

Read Pillow's documentation to learn how to load an image file into an array.

Then, you should usually scale the array into values between 0 and 1. Usually, you just divide the image array by 255 (because they are RGB values between 0 and 255).

Be sure to end up with an array shaped like this: (3000, width, heigth, channels), where channels is usually 3 (Red, green, blue).